# VBA to insert and increment formulae in cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this VBA

```
Sub ApplyCV()
Range("H2:H5000").Formula = "=GetPattern($A2)"
End Sub
```

Which basically applies the custom function "=GetPattern" to execute the macro of the same name. This works fine.

However, instead of explicitly stating the range (which will vary with each dataset) I'd like to increment the formula on a loop UNTIL the last row of data or until there is no cell value in A:whatever.

Any help with this would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the last value in column A (looking from the bottom up) and using that cell's row to define the extent of the range in column H that the formula is applied to.

```
Range("H2:H" & cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row).Formula = "=GetPattern($A2)"
```

Comment: Works perfectly and much simpler than other incremental loops I attempted. Thanks so much!